# $elemMatch against two Array elements if one fails

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

A bit odd but this is what I am looking for.
I have an array as follow:
Document 1:

```
Items: [
{
"ZipCode": "11111",
"ZipCode4" "1234"
}
```

Document 2:

```
Items: [
{
"ZipCode": "11111",
"ZipCode4" "0000"
}
```

I would like to use a single query, and send a filter on `ZipCode = 1111 && ZipCode4 = 4321`, if this fails, the query should look for `ZipCode = 1111 && ZipCode4: 0000`

Is there a way to do this in a single query ? or do I need to make 2 calls to my database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matching both data set (11111/4321) and (11111/0000), you can use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) and [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) with `$elemMatch` like the following :

```
db.test.find({
    $or: [{
        $and: [{
            "Items": {
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode": "11111" }
            }
        }, {
            "Items": {
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode4": "4321" }
            }
        }]
    }, {
        $and: [{
            "Items": {
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode": "11111" }
            }
        }, {
            "Items": {
                $elemMatch: { "ZipCode4": "0000" }
            }
        }]
    }]
})
```

As you want conditional staging, this is not possible but we can get closer to it like this :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $or: [{
            $and: [{ "Items.ZipCode": "11111" }, { "Items.ZipCode4": "4321" }]
        }, {
            $and: [{ "Items.ZipCode": "11111" }, { "Items.ZipCode4": "0000" }]
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        Items: 1,
        match: {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$Items",
                "as": "val",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { $and: [{ "$eq": ["$$val.ZipCode", "11111"] }, { "$eq": ["$$val.ZipCode4", "4321"] }] },
                        true,
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$match"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$match",
        data: {
            $push: {
                _id: "$_id",
                Items: "$Items"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

- The first [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is for selecting only the items we need
- The [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) will build a new field that check if this items is from the 1st set of data (11111/4321) or the 2nd set of data (11111/0000).
- The [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is used to remove the array generated by [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/).
- The [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) group by set of data

So in the end you will have an output like the following :

```
{ "_id" : true, "data" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("58af69ac594b51730a394972"), "Items" : [ { "ZipCode" : "11111", "ZipCode4" : "4321" } ] }, { "_id" : ObjectId("58af69ac594b51730a394974"), "Items" : [ { "ZipCode" : "11111", "ZipCode4" : "4321" } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : false, "data" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("58af69ac594b51730a394971"), "Items" : [ { "ZipCode" : "11111", "ZipCode4" : "0000" } ] } ] }
```

Your application logic can check if there is `_id:true` in this output array, just take the corresponding `data` field for `_id:true`. If there is `_id:false` in this object take the corresponding `data` field for `_id:false`.

In the last `$group`, you can also use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to builds 2 field `data1` & `data2` for both type of data set but this will be painful to use as it will add `null` object to the array for each one of the opposite type :

```
"$addToSet": {
    "$cond": [
        { "$eq": ["$_id", true] },
        "$data",
        null
    ]
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/848d063b0bc4bde577d8290ca7879d95) is a gist

Comment: using this query, if both documents ar ein the DB, it returns both, I need to return the first one, if it exists, if not, return the 2nd one.